# Position Labels on a coordinate System Easeljs

Tags: javascript, html, css, easeljs

Hey I am trying to build the following picture in canvas using the library:[EaselJS](http://www.createjs.com/easeljs).
[image]

My Picture components are:

1. two circles - yellow and red and a light green background
2. a coordinate system from 0 to 1 with all the necessary labels which appear in the picture.

I have succeeded in my two goals. 
I have build a Coordinate System based on stackoverflow discussion:
[How to draw a full coordinate system with Easeljs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769469/how-to-draw-a-full-coordinate-system-with-easeljs).

I have left with 2 main problems which concern me a lot:

1. I need to draw a rectangle(or square) which fits the coordinate system, the current rectangle is just a background.
2. Also I need to add 3 labels: 'Critical Index' on the x axis, 'Long-term Severity Index' on the y axis and a headline of Long-term.

I would happy if someone could help me with this issues
I am adding the source code:

```js
$(function(){
var stage = new createjs.Stage('canvas2d');
var circle1 = new createjs.Shape();
var circle2 = new createjs.Shape();
var rect = new createjs.Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
circle2.graphics.beginFill("yellow").drawCircle(0, 0, 300);
circle2.x = 500;
circle2.y = 0;
stage.addChild(circle2);
circle1.graphics.beginFill("red").drawCircle(0, 0, 150);
circle1.x = 500;
circle1.y = 0;
stage.addChild(circle1);
//stage.addChild(rect);
stage.update();
var coord_xaxis = new createjs.Shape();
stage.addChild(coord_xaxis);
var coord_yaxis = new createjs.Shape();
stage.addChild(coord_yaxis);
var coord_arrow_x = new createjs.Shape();
//stage.addChild(coord_arrow_x);
var coord_arrow_y = new createjs.Shape();
//stage.addChild(coord_arrow_y);
var coord_xaxis_lines = new createjs.Shape();
stage.addChild(coord_xaxis_lines);
var coord_yaxis_lines = new createjs.Shape();
stage.addChild(coord_yaxis_lines);
/**$('#canvas2d').width()/15**/
var axis_center_x = $('#canvas2d').width()/15;
var axis_center_y = $('#canvas2d').height()/1.10;
var xaxis_width = $('#canvas2d').width()-0.05*$('#canvas2d').width();
var yaxis_width = $('#canvas2d').height()-0.05*$('#canvas2d').height();
var axis_start_x = ($('#canvas2d').width()-xaxis_width)/2;
var axis_start_y = ($('#canvas2d').height()-yaxis_width)/6;

var axis_strokewidth = 2;
coord_xaxis.graphics.setStrokeStyle(axis_strokewidth,'round').beginStroke('#000');
coord_xaxis.graphics.moveTo(axis_start_x, axis_center_y).lineTo(axis_start_x+xaxis_width, axis_center_y);
coord_yaxis.graphics.setStrokeStyle(axis_strokewidth,'round').beginStroke('#000');
coord_yaxis.graphics.moveTo(axis_center_x, axis_start_y).lineTo(axis_center_x, axis_start_y+yaxis_width);

// draw coordsys arrow for x-axis
var arrwidth = 5;
var arrxtnd = 5;
coord_arrow_x.graphics.beginFill('#000');
coord_arrow_x.graphics.setStrokeStyle(axis_strokewidth,'round').beginStroke('#000');
coord_arrow_x.graphics.moveTo(axis_center_x, axis_start_y-arrwidth/2).lineTo(axis_center_x+arrwidth, axis_start_y+arrwidth+arrxtnd).lineTo(axis_center_x-arrwidth, axis_start_y+arrwidth+arrxtnd).lineTo(axis_center_x, axis_start_y-arrwidth/2);
coord_arrow_x.graphics.endFill();

// draw coordsys arrow for y-axis
coord_arrow_y.graphics.beginFill('#000');
coord_arrow_y.graphics.beginStroke('#000');
coord_arrow_y.graphics.moveTo(axis_start_x+xaxis_width+arrwidth/2, axis_center_y).lineTo(axis_start_x+xaxis_width-arrwidth-arrxtnd, axis_center_y+arrwidth).lineTo(axis_start_x+xaxis_width-arrwidth-arrxtnd, axis_center_y-arrwidth).lineTo(axis_start_x+xaxis_width+arrwidth/2, axis_center_y);
coord_arrow_y.graphics.endFill();

var stepdist = xaxis_width/5.25;
var steplinew = 6;
// 10 horizontal lines
var xlines = 10;
var labels_x = [];
for(var i=xlines;i>=0;i--) {
 // little black marker
  coord_yaxis_lines.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1,'round').beginStroke('#000');
        coord_yaxis_lines.graphics.moveTo(axis_center_x-steplinew, axis_center_y+(-i/2)*stepdist).lineTo(axis_center_x+steplinew, axis_center_y+(-i/2)*stepdist);
        // labels
        labels_x[i] = new createjs.Text('x', '14px Arial', '#333');
        labels_x[i].x = axis_center_x-12;
        labels_x[i].y = axis_center_y+(-i/2)*stepdist-6; // move up a bit
        stage.addChild(labels_x[i]);
        labels_x[i].text = (i/10);
        labels_x[i].textAlign = 'right';
}
// 12 orthogonal lines
 var stepdist2 = xaxis_width/6.5; 
  var steplinew2 = 6;
var ylines = 10;
var labels_y = [];
for(var i=ylines;i>=1;i--) {
    // dont overdraw y-axis-line
        
        // little black marker
        coord_xaxis_lines.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1,'round').beginStroke('#000');
        coord_xaxis_lines.graphics.moveTo(axis_center_x+(i/1.6)*stepdist2, axis_center_y-steplinew2).lineTo(axis_center_x+(i/1.6)*stepdist2, axis_center_y+steplinew2);           
        // labels
        labels_y[i] = new createjs.Text('x', '14px Arial', '#333');
        labels_y[i].x = axis_center_x+(i/1.6)*stepdist2; // move up a bit
        labels_y[i].y = axis_center_y+12;
        stage.addChild(labels_y[i]);
        labels_y[i].text = (i/10);
        labels_y[i].textAlign = 'center';
}

stage.update(); 
  })
```

```css
#canvas2d{
  background-color: #32CD32;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas2d" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: There's definitely too much repetition in your code. As soon as you get this question solved, I highly recommend you to go over [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) to improve code quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for creating a rectangle in EaselJS is just the same as making a circle. The difference lies when calling `drawRect` instead of `drawCircle` in the `graphics` chain.

I've added a rectangle with arbitrary position and size values to match your overall code style, and because I couldn't find any criteria quickly. I also removed the background color on the CSS.

As for the addition of labels on each axis, I highly recommend you to use DOM instead. EaselJS support for text is almost unusable. Even EaselJS itself recommends you to use a `DOMElement` instead of the `Text` `DisplayObj`. More on `DOMElement` [here](http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DOMElement.html).

Personally, I think it would be a lot easier to get to your desired result by using pure DOM instead of canvas work, unless you're doing some heavy user-interaction-based animation stuff.

```js
$(function(){
var stage = new createjs.Stage('canvas2d');
var circle1 = new createjs.Shape();
var circle2 = new createjs.Shape();
var rect = new createjs.Shape();
rect.graphics.f("green").drawRect(33, 0, 500, 455);
stage.addChild(rect);
circle2.graphics.beginFill("yellow").drawCircle(0, 0, 300);
circle2.x = 500;
circle2.y = 0;
stage.addChild(circle2);
circle1.graphics.beginFill("red").drawCircle(0, 0, 150);
circle1.x = 500;
circle1.y = 0;
stage.addChild(circle1);
stage.update();
var coord_xaxis = new createjs.Shape();
stage.addChild(coord_xaxis);
var coord_yaxis = new createjs.Shape();
stage.addChild(coord_yaxis);
var coord_arrow_x = new createjs.Shape();
//stage.addChild(coord_arrow_x);
var coord_arrow_y = new createjs.Shape();
//stage.addChild(coord_arrow_y);
var coord_xaxis_lines = new createjs.Shape();
stage.addChild(coord_xaxis_lines);
var coord_yaxis_lines = new createjs.Shape();
stage.addChild(coord_yaxis_lines);
/**$('#canvas2d').width()/15**/
var axis_center_x = $('#canvas2d').width()/15;
var axis_center_y = $('#canvas2d').height()/1.10;
var xaxis_width = $('#canvas2d').width()-0.05*$('#canvas2d').width();
var yaxis_width = $('#canvas2d').height()-0.05*$('#canvas2d').height();
var axis_start_x = ($('#canvas2d').width()-xaxis_width)/2;
var axis_start_y = ($('#canvas2d').height()-yaxis_width)/6;

var axis_strokewidth = 2;
coord_xaxis.graphics.setStrokeStyle(axis_strokewidth,'round').beginStroke('#000');
coord_xaxis.graphics.moveTo(axis_start_x, axis_center_y).lineTo(axis_start_x+xaxis_width, axis_center_y);
coord_yaxis.graphics.setStrokeStyle(axis_strokewidth,'round').beginStroke('#000');
coord_yaxis.graphics.moveTo(axis_center_x, axis_start_y).lineTo(axis_center_x, axis_start_y+yaxis_width);

// draw coordsys arrow for x-axis
var arrwidth = 5;
var arrxtnd = 5;
coord_arrow_x.graphics.beginFill('#000');
coord_arrow_x.graphics.setStrokeStyle(axis_strokewidth,'round').beginStroke('#000');
coord_arrow_x.graphics.moveTo(axis_center_x, axis_start_y-arrwidth/2).lineTo(axis_center_x+arrwidth, axis_start_y+arrwidth+arrxtnd).lineTo(axis_center_x-arrwidth, axis_start_y+arrwidth+arrxtnd).lineTo(axis_center_x, axis_start_y-arrwidth/2);
coord_arrow_x.graphics.endFill();

// draw coordsys arrow for y-axis
coord_arrow_y.graphics.beginFill('#000');
coord_arrow_y.graphics.beginStroke('#000');
coord_arrow_y.graphics.moveTo(axis_start_x+xaxis_width+arrwidth/2, axis_center_y).lineTo(axis_start_x+xaxis_width-arrwidth-arrxtnd, axis_center_y+arrwidth).lineTo(axis_start_x+xaxis_width-arrwidth-arrxtnd, axis_center_y-arrwidth).lineTo(axis_start_x+xaxis_width+arrwidth/2, axis_center_y);
coord_arrow_y.graphics.endFill();

var stepdist = xaxis_width/5.25;
var steplinew = 6;
// 10 horizontal lines
var xlines = 10;
var labels_x = [];
for(var i=xlines;i>=0;i--) {
 // little black marker
  coord_yaxis_lines.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1,'round').beginStroke('#000');
        coord_yaxis_lines.graphics.moveTo(axis_center_x-steplinew, axis_center_y+(-i/2)*stepdist).lineTo(axis_center_x+steplinew, axis_center_y+(-i/2)*stepdist);
        // labels
        labels_x[i] = new createjs.Text('x', '14px Arial', '#333');
        labels_x[i].x = axis_center_x-12;
        labels_x[i].y = axis_center_y+(-i/2)*stepdist-6; // move up a bit
        stage.addChild(labels_x[i]);
        labels_x[i].text = (i/10);
        labels_x[i].textAlign = 'right';
}
// 12 orthogonal lines
 var stepdist2 = xaxis_width/6.5; 
  var steplinew2 = 6;
var ylines = 10;
var labels_y = [];
for(var i=ylines;i>=1;i--) {
    // dont overdraw y-axis-line
        
        // little black marker
        coord_xaxis_lines.graphics.setStrokeStyle(1,'round').beginStroke('#000');
        coord_xaxis_lines.graphics.moveTo(axis_center_x+(i/1.6)*stepdist2, axis_center_y-steplinew2).lineTo(axis_center_x+(i/1.6)*stepdist2, axis_center_y+steplinew2);           
        // labels
        labels_y[i] = new createjs.Text('x', '14px Arial', '#333');
        labels_y[i].x = axis_center_x+(i/1.6)*stepdist2; // move up a bit
        labels_y[i].y = axis_center_y+12;
        stage.addChild(labels_y[i]);
        labels_y[i].text = (i/10);
        labels_y[i].textAlign = 'center';
}

stage.update(); 
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas2d" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks , what about the labels, how can I place the labels?

Comment: @Brk I explain why I haven't helped you with that at the third and fourth paragraph.

Comment: Text manipulation with EaselJS is so heavily limited that I refused to learn about how it can be done at all. Just use DOM instead, or do it exactly how you've done with the numbers on each axis by duplicating them and changing their coordinates and value.

Comment: how can I do it with DOM Elements,can you show me an example on my current code?
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Brk a `DOMElement` is normally an element in your HTML file, such as a `span` tag. You can then append EaselJS `DisplayObj` properties to it by calling `var myDOMElement = new createjs.DOMElement("mySpan")`. Then it's position can be easily changed by using it's `x` and `y` properties. But as I said before, the job could be done a lot easier by using pure HTML and CSS.

Comment: Sufficient explanation can be found at the [EaselJS documentation](http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/DOMElement.html), which is one of the best documentations I have ever seen.

Comment: Excellent, but how can I add text to this DOM Element?

Comment: `<span id="mySpan">Here's the text you're asking for</span>`